# My project can't find its libraries when run manually from the terminal

Tags: c++, dll, shared-libraries, qt-creator

I'm creating a library for the first time. So far it's working from the IDE (Qt Creator), but not from the terminal when I run its testing program manually.

There are two parts to my project, the library, and the sandbox for testing it. I've created a project in Qt Creator that includes two subprojects (one to build the lib, and one to build the tester) and both compile without errors. When I run the sandbox from the IDE the library is dynamically linked to the sandbox, the function `greeting()` is loaded in from it, then called, and prints "Welcome to the library!" to `std::cout`. However, if I open the build folder in the terminal and run the sandbox directly using `./sandbox` I get:

```
./sandbox: error while loading shared libraries: libengine.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I took this to mean that I needed to properly install my custom library, `libengine.so.1`. When I looked up how to do that I found that I just needed to copy the library files in to either, `/usr/lib` or `/usr/local/lib`, but neither of those worked and I'm still getting the above error. In the past, that simple solution did work for me when compiling a 3rd party library (SDL, I think) and I don't know what I'm missing that would mean it wouldn't work now. So far I haven't yet found any more detailed information and I don't know what I'm doing wrong or have missed.

How do I make my sandbox program see its companion library when I run it directly from the command line?

**NOTE**: I'm specifically asking about Linux/Ubuntu. If I later run into problems under Windows I'll be back. :-)

Comment: Did you try: man ldconfig

Comment: I have not, nor do I know what that is. However, I just got it working a moment ago! Should I update my question, or post an answer separately?

Comment: It's ok to post answers to your own question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short Answer

I ran in to multiple problems all at once.

- First problem: Broken symbolic links (they're like shortcuts in Windows).
- Second: My lib needed to be copied in to a different system directory than is generally recommended.
- Third: Qt Creator and QMake made passing custom linker options difficult.

---

## The Details

When Qt Creator compiles my library it automatically creates three symbolic links to it with different layouts of the version numbers.

```
> ll
lib-engine.so -> lib-engine.so.0.1.0
lib-engine.so.0 -> lib-engine.so.0.1.0
lib-engine.so.0.1 -> lib-engine.so.0.1.0
lib-engine.so.0.1.0 (original library file)
```

For some reason (I don't know why) each time I moved the links in to a system directory like `usr/local/lib` the links would break. I didn't notice this at first, or even think to check, because that's never happened to me before. Moving a link has always worked in the past. To get around this I just manually created the links within the directories they would reside in.

Broken links aside, putting the library in to `usr/local/lib` still didn't work, but `usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` (recommended in the blog linked below) did work!

Those fixes actually came after a different fix I looked in to after reading [this blog](https://aimlesslygoingforward.com/blog/2014/01/19/bundling-shared-libraries-on-linux/) and [this article](https://www.eyrie.org/%7Eeagle/notes/rpath.html) it linked to.

There it said to add `-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib'` to the gcc build options to embed a library search path in to the application itself. This set of options would allow me to put my library files where ever I wanted (specifically, in a directory called /lib in the application's working directory).

Unfortunately, that had two problems of its own. First, Qt Creator doesn't (from what I can tell) allow you to specify custom build options for individual subprojects through the GUI, so I had to figure out how to add linker options using the project file, assuming that was possible, which it was.

Second, QMake messed up the gcc options, embedding in to my application `Library rpath: [RIGIN/lib]` instead of `Library rpath: [lib]` like it's supposed to.

In the end, changing the proposed linker options of...

```
-Wl,-rpath,'$ORIGIN/lib'
```

... to the following QMake project file line...

```
QMAKE_LFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,'lib'
```

... work out nicely. Using both fixes I can now either install my library on my system or put it in to a /lib folder and the program will run.